# Array Instantiation

Tags: java

Can you help me out with this question please.

Question: 
Given the following array declarations

```
double readings[];
String urls[];
TicketMachine[] machines;
```

write assignments that accomplish the following tasks:

- make the `readings` variable refer to an array that is able to hold sixty `double` values
- make the `urls` variable refer to an array that is able to hold ninety `String` objects
- make the `machines` variable refer to an array that is able to hold five `TicketMachine` objects

My answer:

```
//declare and instantiate object

double readings [] = new double [60];

String urls [] = new String [90];

TicketMachine machines [] = new TicketMachine [5];
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
Main.java:16: readings is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

double readings [] = new double [60];
       ^

Main.java:17: urls is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

String urls [] = new String [90];
       ^

Main.java:18: machines is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

TicketMachine machines [] = new TicketMachine [5];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you declare the variables, you don't need to mention their type again on future assignments.

Thus, if you do:

```
int i;
int i = 5;
```

then you've redeclared the type of `i`, which is an error. Instead, just do:

```
int i;
i = 5;
```

Or even better, you can combine the two into one statement:

```
int i = 5;
```

Since the variables in your particular example have already been declared as a particular type, then you can just do:

```
readings = ...;
urls = ...;
machines = ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

you've already declared those variables, so now you can just instantiate them

```
readings = new double[60];
urls = new String[90];
machines = new TicketMachine[5];
```